# Programmatically detect Windows cluster configuration?

Tags: windows, cluster-computing

Does anyone know how to programatically detect that a Windows server is part of a cluster?

Further, is it possible to detect that the server is the active or passive node?

[Edit] And detect it from Win32?  A registry setting maybe?

Thanks for any insight.

Doug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have an exact answer, but there are lots of APIs beginning with "Cluster" (like ClusterOpenEnum and ClusterNodeEnum) and COM interfaces beginning with "IGetCluster" that look promising.

Comment: API documentation?

Answer (score 4):

You can use WMI to lookup the information. That should work from XP/Win32 etc.

There is some great information here on using VBScript to do the job:
http://www.activexperts.com/activmonitor/windowsmanagement/scripts/networking/clustering/

Here's some C#/.Net code that also uses WMI:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System;
using System.Management;

namespace SandboxConsole
{
    public class ClusterAdmin
    {
        [MTAThread]
        public static void Main()
        {
            string clusterName = "MyCluster"; // cluster alias
            string custerGroupResource = "FS_Resource1"; // Cluster group name
            ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions();
            options.Username = "ClusterAdmin"; //could be in domain\user format
            options.Password = "HisPassword";

            // Connect with the mscluster WMI namespace on the cluster named "MyCluster"
            ManagementScope s = new ManagementScope("\\\\" + clusterName + "\\root\\mscluster", options);
            ManagementPath p = new ManagementPath("Mscluster_Clustergroup.Name='" + custerGroupResource + "'");

            using (ManagementObject clrg = new ManagementObject(s, p, null))
            {
                // Take clustergroup off line and read its status property when done
                TakeOffLine(clrg);
                clrg.Get();
                Console.WriteLine(clrg["Status"]);

                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000); // Sleep for a while

                // Bring back online and get status.
                BringOnLine(clrg);
                clrg.Get();
                Console.WriteLine(clrg["Status"]);
            }
        }
        static void TakeOffLine(ManagementObject resourceGroup)
        {
            ManagementBaseObject outParams =
            resourceGroup.InvokeMethod("Takeoffline", null, null);
        }
        static void BringOnLine(ManagementObject resourceGroup)
        {
            ManagementBaseObject outParams =
            resourceGroup.InvokeMethod("Takeoffline", null, null);
        }
    }
}
```

I found this code [here](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/261632-cluster-api) and tidied it up a little.

Comment: Bringonline wrong?

Comment: http://www.activexperts.com/activmonitor/windowsmanagement/scripts/networking/clustering/ not found

Answer (score 1):

Any specific language you're looking for?

You might be able to employ the [**failover cluster cmdlets for Powershell**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee461009.aspx) (for Windows Server 2008 R2).  Specifically `Get-Cluster` and `Get-ClusterNode`

Comment: Thanks.  I need it for Win32, but that is a starting point for me to at least look at.